# React Native Android App crash: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, realm

When I run the app:

```
react-native run-android
```

On physical devices the application sometimes (just sometimes) when it has to interact with Realm DB the app just closes itself without visible error. while in Android Emulator it works okay.

In android studio Logcat, as error throws me this when the app crashes:

```
2020-08-26 18:17:22.063 21369-21417/com.geslubapp A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 21417 (mqt_js), pid 21369 (com.geslubapp)
```

[image]

Version:

react-native: 0.62.2
react: 16.11.0

Comment: I am also getting the same problem. How did you solve this problem. ??

Comment: I downgrade Realm library. See https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/3177

Comment: But realm version 6 is required for react native 0.62.2. for ios . As it is not linking below that version in ios.So how did you solve the problem for ios.

Comment: I'm working with ios as well and I dont have problems with Realm v3 so far

Comment: Any updates? https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31710